# How do I make webview findInPage() work in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if search is broken right now.

When creating the webview I do:

```
webview.addEventListener('found-in-page', function(e)
{
    webview.stopFindInPage('keepSelection')
})
```

And I call it manually like:

`webview.findInPage('word')`

The word exists in the current document, yet e.result always shows 0 matches, and no word is highlighted (though I'm not sure if I should do this manually).

This is on Electron 5.0.2

https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the electron-context-menu library. Using it messed up the findInPage method.